# Make Google Apps script with regex in loop use less resources, so not to exceed maximum execution time

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

Is there a way to make this script use less resources? I get exceeded maxiumum execution time, even when only selecting a small portion of the dataset.

I suppose the Regex consumes quite a bit of resources, particularly since it's done for every iteration of the source column, for each iteration of the target column. But I'm not sure how to solve it, to make it possible to run this through a large amount of data.

```
function updatecategory() {
 /* let us say source array with name(columnA) & ID(columnB) is array 'source'
and target array with only IDs is array 'target', you get these with something like*/
var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[4].getDataRange().getValues();
// and
var target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0].getRange("A3:A30").getValues();// if other columns, change index values in the arrays : 0=A, 1=B ...
//   then let's create a 3 rd array that will be the new target with ID + names, and call it 'newtarget' 
var newtarget=new Array()
// the iteration could be like this :
      for(i=0;i<target.length;++i){ // don't miss any ID
        var found=""
        var targetstr = target[i][0].toString()

       for(j=0;j<source.length;++j){ // iterate through source to find the name
         for(k=2;k<3;++k){
           var str = source[j][k].toString()
           var regex = new RegExp(".(?!(?!.*.[a-zA-Z ]{2,}" + targetstr + ")(?!" + targetstr + "[a-zA-Z \*]+$)).*$", "gm") 
           //Find only words in a cell that exactly match the target word,
           //that is not part of a word or a phrase.

           var replace = ''
           var newstr = str.replace(regex,replace)

           if(newstr.indexOf(targetstr)>-1){
             var newsource = source[j][0] + "(n)"
             var newtargetrow=[target[i][0], newsource] // if match found, store it with name (idx0) and ID (idx 1)
             //Logger.log(target[i][0].toString().match(source[j][0].toString()) + " " + source[j][0].toString())
             //newtarget.push(newtargetrow);// store result in new array with 2 columns
             found="found"
             Logger.log(targetstr + " " + newsource)
           } else if (found != "found") {
             var newtargetrow=[target[i][0], ''] // if no match, show it in name column
             //Logger.log(found)
           }
         }
       }
        //Logger.log(newtarget)
         newtarget.push(newtargetrow);// store result in new array with 2 columns
       //loop source



     } // loop target

     /* now you have a newtarget array that can directly overwrite the old target 
    using setValues() */
    var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];// assuming the target sheet is sheet nr2
    sh.getRange(3,1,newtarget.length,newtarget[0].length).setValues(newtarget);
//
```

}

Comment: Looks like you need to replace your RegExp declaration to `var regex = new RegExp("\\b" + targetstr + "\\b", "g");`

Comment: Thanks @stribizhev! What if the target "word" that I'm looking for in the source cell is actually two words? It could be "take off", for example. Then \b wouldn't work? Each word in the source cell is separated with comma or semi-colon, by the way.

Comment: The [word boundary `\b`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) won't work if your `str` starts or ends with a non-word character (that is, other than one from `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` set). Otherwise, it should ensure whole word matching.

Comment: Does it work for you? Shall I post that as an answer?

Comment: It works to find the words to look for, yes. But then the replace function replaces those matches, which means it finds "whereabouts" instead of "about". I tried to use `var newstr = str.search(regex)`, but it doesn't work. I suppose what I need to do is to reverse your regex above, to match everything _except_ `targetstr`

Comment: It does not make sense. `alert("whereabout".replace(/\babout\b/g, ""));` will not remove the `about`. There is something that does not "click" here.

Comment: Well, `if(newstr.indexOf(targetstr)>-1)` should match _only_ if newstr contains the targetstr _exactly_. That is, if the targetstr is _about_, `if(newstr.indexOf(targetstr)>-1)` should only be true if newstr looks like `word, about, another word`, but not if newstr looks like `word, whereabout, another word`. Maybe there's something else I miss in the logic...

Comment: I do not understand what you want to achieve: first, you remove all `targetstr` that are whole words from the `str`, and then you are looking for them again in `newstr`? That is pointless.

Comment: Which is why there is something else in the logic I need to change. I tried change the if statement to `if(regex.test(str))`, but then if I search for _about_, it returns true also if the string looks like `word, this is about, word 2`. So the regex still needs to check that the word is not part of a larger string somehow.

Comment: So, you just need the start/end of line anchors: `var regex = new RegExp("(?:^|\\s)" + targetstr + "(?=\\s|$)", "gm");`, right?

Comment: Well, that matches only if the word is in the very beginning of the string. But it can also appear anywhere in the string, such as `word, about, word`. It should match that string, but not `word, this is about, word`

Comment: Ah, I see you edited your comment :) Now this also matches `round about` and `about it`. But now we're getting closer :D

Comment: I did get it working, using `var regex = new RegExp("(^|(,|;)\\s)\\b" + targetstr + "\\b(?!\\s)", "gm")`. Thanks a lot for your help, @stribizhev!

Comment: Great, I enhanced it a bit and posted as an answer. Please consider accepting if it is working for you and upvoting if it is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your feedback, you can use

```
var regex = new RegExp("(^|[,;]\\s)\\b" + targetstr + "\\b(?!\\s)", "gm")
```

It matches a `targetstr` that is a whole word (because of `\b` word boundary anchors round the term) and is preceded by a start-of-line anchor (`^`) or a comma or semi-colon followed with a whitespace (`[,;]\\s`) *and* that is not followed with whitespace (`(?!\\s)`).